# Why does Python only read the no data value from GeoTIFF?

Tags: python, gdal

I had a number of TIFF files with a country's map. They had different rows, columns or different projections etc. I needed to make them with same projection, spatial resolution and same number of rows and columns. So I used `QGIS Raster->Projections-> Warp(Reproject)` method and a vector boundary shapefile to get `TIFF` files with the intended parameters.

After doing this each file contained **two bands**. One band with the original data values and another band with values from 0 to 255. (I think it is for visualization, is it?)

In some of these files I had specified no data values and in others, I didn't. But when I'm reading these files in `numpy` arrays in Python using `gdal`, I'm only getting an array of intended size `(53,54)` **but with  no data values!** I used the following code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from gdalconst import *
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import os, glob
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r"H:\...\Processed")
#load tiff files in numpy arrays
ds1 = gdal.Open("cases2001.tiff")
can01 = np.array(ds1.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) #data type is float64
print can01.shape
ds2 = gdal.Open("cases2002.tiff")
can02 = np.array(ds2.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) #data type is float 64
print can02.shape
#Load the RASTER CLIPPED REPROJECTED IMAGE AM I DOING SOME MISTAKE HERE?
ds3 = gdal.Open(r"H:\...\Annual 53-54\AOD2001.tiff")
AOD01 = np.array(ds3.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
AOD01 =AOD01.astype('float64')  #Convertinf to float data type
print AOD01.shape
print AOD01
```

**Why am I not getting the required values? And instead ending up with the "no data values"?** For the files `cases2001` and `cases2002`, which are the original files according to which I re-projected my other files are having the perfect, intended values. But for the third file here i.e. `AOD2001` I'm getting an array of zeroes (I didn't change the default no data value). I've tried for both bands. But in `QGIS` "Identify Features" I'm getting the correct values for the 1st band. But not while reading ion Python.  I've already tried masking and a few other suggestions for similar problems (such as`GetStatistics` not refreshing etc) but I haven't found exact problem anywhere yet.

On a side note I need to plot these 2-D arrays against each other and perform regression. Which I'm obviously getting incorrect same values for each row as the `AOD2001` file contains only zeroes. Another question, **Can we compare (In my case perform regression on) two tiff files with same dimension, same spatial resolution and same end coordinates but different origins?**

It's the first time I'm asking a question here, so I may have made mistakes in formatting etc., please point it out, I'd edit and take care in future. Also, please tell me if I should provide some other information or data.

Comment: it's not clear to me yet why there are two bands simply after reprojecting the raster -  but aside from that, is there a reason the new array must be cast as float64? And you are certain the new array contains only zeros? (could use `AOD01.min()` or `AOD01.max()` to verify the range of values.